# CentOS restore firewall after `service iptables panic`

Tags: centos, iptables

My friend and I were doing some firewall configurations and in the meanwhile he thought it was a good idea to type `service iptables panic`.

Now we cannot put the firewall back on the original state (default). It blocks all connections. We have tried everything:

```
iptables -F service 
iptables save service 
iptables stop service 
iptables start etc....
```

What can we do to restore original and clean firewall configurations?

Comment: I just tried running your command on a normal CentOS 6.4 Desktop installation could not reproduce your error so you could have further issues. What error are you getting  when trying to start the service and what do you see in the various log files?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The only thing that worked was to:

```
$ setup
```

and activate all services on firewall again.

Answer (score 0):

Running `iptables` commands from the commandline only alters the running configuration.
Depending on how you set up iptables to save configurations in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`, your configuration might still saved in saved in the file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables/iptables.save`
To restore the configuration saved in this file run:

```
# iptables-restore /etc/sysconfig/iptables.save
```

If you have no configuration saved, you can set the default INPUT policy to accept by running

```
# iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```